# React Native Autocompletion IntelliJ

Tags: reactjs, react-native, intellij-idea, autocomplete

When I create own "Wrapper"-components, the auto-completion is not working for me.

e.g. my TextInput:

```
const TextInput = props => {

    const {error} = props
    let borderColor = Colors.grey

    if (error) borderColor = Colors.error

    return (
        <TextInputCmp style={{...styles.input, borderColor}} {...props}/>
    )
}

export default TextInput
```

All props of the normal TextInput + additional ones like `error` should be allowed and therfore suggested by the IDE.

I know, the IDE cannot know this. Please tell me what to do (adopt code / install plugins) to get a working autocompletion when wrapping these components.

Comment: Please don't include "Thanks" or similar in your question. See meta for reasoning/details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding/working with typescript solved this issue for me.
I really can recommend using typescript. https://www.typescriptlang.org/